# Setting Moment.js default date format to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: date, localization, momentjs

When calling `.calendar()` in Moment.js, dates are output using the `MM/DD/YYYY` format. From looking at the code, this appears to be controlled by the `L` token. Likewise, the `LL` token outputs the date as *November 29 2013*.

The only problem is, these are US date formats and I need to display mine according to Australian standards, e.g. `DD/MM/YYYY` and *29 November 2013*.

Does anyone know where/ how to set this?

NB: My system locale and location are set to *English (Australia)* and *Australia* respectively.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to use the moment-with-lang.js and set the language for "Australia"

check the docs here http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/changing-locale/

for you it should be something like `moment.lang('en-AU');`

Comment: `lang` is deprecated now. Use `locale`.

Answer (score 11):

Using [moment-with-lang.js](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-langs.js) , the code

```
<script src="moment-with-langs.js"></script>
time = moment("Dec 25, 1995");
moment(time).calendar() // note the absence of moment.lang("en-AU");
```

outputs

```
25/12/1995
```

In contrast, using `moment.lang("en-AU");` we get that

```
moment.lang("en-AU");
moment(time).calendar();
```

outputs

```
25/12/1995
```

You can also hardcode the desired output, but using `format()`

```
moment(time).format("D MMMM YYYY")
```

outputs

```
25 December 1995
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amp, it's spot on. I've accepted the previous answer only because they got in first, but for those playing at home this is also a working solution.

Comment: thanks for the comment Nick - agreed! I thought I'd give a bit more examples with output, but Anto is definitely correct!

Answer (score 9):

From version **2.8.1 and newer**, use `locale`:

```
moment.locale('en-AU');
```

If you are using a version **older than 2.8.1**, use `lang`:

```
moment.lang('en-AU');
```

This will set the locale globally in `moment`, and all the locale-dependents functions will be affected after setting this.

Note that this is not available prior to version 1.7.0.

See [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/).

Comment: I feel like I'm doing something wrong.
I'm on V 2.11.1

moment.locale('en-AU');
alert(moment('18/01/2016').format("D MMMM YYYY"));

Still invalid?